# html form to send information to both database & email address

Tags: html, forms

I have a question. I have a current html form that sends data to database using php/ sql query. This is what my form looked like:

```
<form method="POST">
</form>
```

My question is can I add action in there as well? Like

```
<form method="POST" action="email_process.php">
```

Comment: This is what my form looked like: 
<form method="POST">

can I add action in there as well? Like
<form method="POST" action="email_process.php">

Comment: If you add an `action` attribute, what will happen is that the form sends data to that script, instead of the current script.

Comment: Yes. This is how forms work. Without the `action` attribute, the POST request will be sent to whatever your current URL is.

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="email_process.php">` you just did. *Congratulations!*

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to `POST` to a page that is not itself, you **must** put the `action` attribute in the opening `form` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="email_process.php">
    <!-- form inputs here -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it:

```
<form method="POST" action="email_process.php">
```

The email_process.php file/pages must be at same directory.

If you would like to refer another directory, then must override action="email_process.php" to action="./../email/email_process.php"